# Position of sprites at different resolutions

Tags: android, libgdx

I know it is an old subject but here is my way to dealing with different resolutions

I get sprites x and y then divide them by 800 and 480

For example if I had an sprite at 150 and 50 on 800 and 480 
it will be at 0.1875 * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and 0.1041 * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() on another screen resolutions

but the problem is this doesn't go well for all resolutions as there are big variations when sprite is at high resolution in comparison to small one

Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Viewports`: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

The `Viewport` does basically all the resolution math for you.

This is how it works:
You choose a world size of your choice. For example: 400 width, 300 height. The unit does not matter.

When you place a sprite at position (200, 150) the left bottom corner of that sprite will be in the center of the screen no matter which resolution.

The calculation from your world coordinate to the screen coordinate will be done for you by the `Viewport`.

Comment: I manage the size of sprites by another way other than viewports I only want to manage the position 
can this be achieved by viewports ?